# Roboelectric - upgrading from version 1.2 to 2.1

Tags: android, unit-testing

I've inherited an Android application which has unit tests written using Roboelectric version 1.2. I've just replaced the version 1.2 jar with the version 2.1 jar (and replaced the old `com.extremelabs.roboelectric` imports with the new `org.roboelectric` imports). The change has largely worked okay except that there are now some methods which are showing as non-existent. Notably:

- Robolectric.bindShadowClass(Class)
- RobolectricTestRunner.addClassOrPackageToInstrument(String)
- RobolectricTestRunner.bindShadowClasses()

Does anyone know where I can find these methods in version 2.1??

Comment: They've got rid of most of the shadows. GL!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The binding of shadow classes is now replaced with @Config annotations.

Example:

```
@Config(shadows = {ShadowSettings.ShadowSecure.class})
```

See also [my answer to this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7250086/how-does-exactly-custom-shadow-objects-work-in-robolectric/17847648#17847648) and [the Robolectric blog](http://robolectric.blogspot.com/2013/05/configuring-robolectric-20.html).