# How to add shadow class when using Robolectric 2.2?

Tags: robolectric

I am using `Robolectric` for my Unit testing and updated my `Robolectric` jar from 1.2 to 2.2 and trying to figure out how to bind shadow classes in this new version. This is what I was doing before:

```
Robolectric.bindShadowClass(ShadowLog.class);

@Implements(Log.class)
public static class ShadowLog {
    public static int i(java.lang.String tag, java.lang.String msg) {
        System.out.println("[" + tag + "] " + msg);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

But I think now there is no bindShadowClass API available. I tried using addShadowClass but I am not sure if this is the right way to add a shadow class. Can I just use

```
ShadowMap a = new ShadowMap.Builder().addShadowClass(ShadowLog.class).build();
```

Do I need to create a classHandler or something using this shadowMap and if yes, how do I create and use that classHandler to get access to my Log class methods?

```
@Implements(Log.class)
public static class ShadowLog {
    public static int i(java.lang.String tag, java.lang.String msg) {
        System.out.println("[" + tag + "] " + msg);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And then `Log.i("LogTest", "log message ");`

Thanks
Abhi

Comment: The binding of shadow classes is now replaced with @Config annotations.

Example:

@Config(shadows = {ShadowLog.class})

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The binding of shadow classes is now replaced with `@Config` annotations.

Example:

```
@Config(shadows = {ShadowLog.class})
```

See also [my answer to this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7250086/how-does-exactly-custom-shadow-objects-work-in-robolectric/17847648#17847648) and [the Robolectric blog](http://robolectric.blogspot.com/2013/05/configuring-robolectric-20.html).