# Shadow classes that reside in dalvik.system.* with Robolectic

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit, robolectric

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7252694/1053803) answer I found that Robolectric intercepts and instruments only classes that reside in:

```
android.* 
com.google.android.maps.* 
org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector
```

In my application I use `dalvik.system.DexFile` ([reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/dalvik/system/DexFile.html)) and because it doesn't belong to either of those packages i am getting `RuntimeException: Stub!` even if i define my Shadow for this class.

Is there any way to add additional packages that Robolectric must intercept? Or is there another approach?

Comment: Have you bound your shadow class?

Comment: Yes. As i've said the problem is with package of the class that you shadow.